# How come Ruby code is showing Hex Code for array instead of the input?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

Ruby is giving me hex code instead of what I assigned the values in my array to. This is the main issue in a bigger thing where I use nested classes to look up dates for dentist's appointments and I believe I narrowed the problem in my code down to this. I copied this into another compiler to see if it was the case and it seems like. Not sure what I'm missing here. Why does it give my hex instead of "desc, month, day, year"?

```
class Appointment
  attr_accessor :desc,:month,:day,:year

  def initialize(desc, month, day, year)
    @desc = desc
    @month = month
    @day = day
    @year = year
  end
end

arr1 = Appointment.new("Description", 6, 18, 1998)
array = [arr1]
puts array
```

Output `ruby main.rb #<Appointment:0x0000558dc54650e8>`

Comment: That's the default output when you call `.to_s` on a class (ie `#<$CLASSNAME:0x$ADDRESS>`) - if you want to dump the member variables, try `puts array.inspect`

Comment: Try this: `arr1.desc #=> "Description"; arr1.month #=> 6; arr1.day #=> 18; arr1.year #=> 1998`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, #to_s prints the object’s class and an encoding of the object id. One option would be to `puts array.inspect` as suggested by @Will Richardson. Another option is to override the default #to_s behavior:

```
class Appointment
  attr_accessor :desc,:month,:day,:year

  def initialize(desc, month, day, year)
    @desc = desc
    @month = month
    @day = day
    @year = year
  end

  # Example override
  def to_s
    "#{desc} on #{month}/#{day}/#{year}"
  end
    
end
```

Then

```
arr1 = Appointment.new("Description", 6, 18, 1998)
array = [arr1]
puts array
```

will output

```
Description on 6/18/1998
```

Though as a side note, you may want to look into the ruby Date or DateTime classes for storing the month, day, and year.

Date: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

DateTime: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll take a look at it soon and get back. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by Joshua Pereira is correct, here is another approach you may find helpful.

You define a class but don't tell the class "how to display itself", i.e. you did not provide a `to_s` method. You could of course define in your class such a method,

```
def to_s
  "Appointment: #{desc} #{month} #{day} #{year}"
end
```

but since your `Appointment` class mainly seems to be a container for the 4 values, you could also define your class by

```
Appointment=Struct.new(:desc, :month, :day, :year)
```

One advantage is that this automatically creates a `to_s` for you. For instance, the following code,

```
arr1 = Appointment.new("Description", 6, 18, 1998)
puts arr1
```

produces the output:

*#<struct Appointment desc="Description", month=6, day=18, year=1998>*

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll take a look at your answer as well to see if that helps. I appreciate it